# BackButton calls previous activity

Tags: android, main-activity

Use of this code I call Next Activity.

**Code**

```
public void click_contact(View v)
{
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
 MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
 overridePendingTransition (R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
 finish();
}
```

So 'ContactActivity' is lunched.
when the built-in "back" button from my device is pressed,the previous activity ('MainActivity') is closed.
But I want relaunch this activity.

Comment: you are calling `finish` so your activity is destroyed. you will have to start the `MainActivity` again. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Remove finish() from your code. As per Activity life cycle for destroying an activity you have to call finish() method from activity.

Comment: i want the users to be able to go back to the previous activity by pressing back button on their phone, but removing 'finish()' doesn't resolve the problem. with or without calling the 'finish()', pressing back closes my app.

Comment: @raulpop8 check this http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html. Rethink your design.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you shouldn't call `finish` and just allow the android system to control the back button.  See (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for details on how it manages.  If your app is closing when back is pressed, perhaps something else is happening that you're not aware of.  Check logcat to see if there are any surprising messages.

Comment: Means you need to Exit from app when user click on built-in "Back" button.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks! I will read that :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want restore your MainActivity then you should remove **finish()** from your code.
**Code**

```
public void click_contact(View v)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    overridePendingTransition (R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

If you want restart MainActivity on back in ContactActivity then you should start it in onBackPressed():

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ContactActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to override onBackPressed.  This will add the MainActivity to the Activity back stack instead of going back to the MainActivity.  (See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: Ok. But what if I am using onBackPressed() in my MainAcitivity to show a AlertDialog, if the users want to close the app or not. Should I remove this dialog, or there is any other way to use both codes for onBackPressed()?

Comment: @raulpop8 I think overriding onBackPressed to show confirmation dialog is ok, but to navigate to the previous Activity it isn't required, and I believe, incorrect to do so.

Comment: @brainestey  To avoid the stacking the same activity you must use the FLAG "FLAG_BRING_TO_FRONT" in the intent.

Comment: I suppose you could do that but I don't think that is necessary for the scenario the OP is trying to achieve.  Showing a second Activity and then going back to the first is a common scenario and handled by Android.

Comment: It depends of needed scenario. In some cases you need to restart activity instead of return to previous instance of backstack.

Comment: used @Dimmerg way, and it worked. Now I am reading the links you guys left in comments. Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Seriously Don't mind . You can obtain what you needed by this method .i don't think this is a right approach(Some exceptions may occur)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the finsh(); at last line and try. Then you will get your Main Activity on pressing back button.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: removing it doesn't resolve the problem. with or without calling the 'finish()', pressing back closes my app.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding backPress will start new intent. That is not good! just dont right finish(). I guess that should automatically take u to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code

```
    public void click_contact(View v){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    overridePendingTransition (R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    finish();
}
```

Why you use `finish()` .By using finish you are removing or  the activity(**in your case MainActivity**) from the activity stack .Or you can say the activity will not get added to stack . So on back press there will not be any activity to load . So do not use  `finish()`

Just use

```
startActivity(new Intent(ContactActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition (R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

So by removing finish your **MainActivity** will get added to the activity stack  and on back press in your **ContactActivity** it will automatically load your **MainActivity**

Have an eye over [**this**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove `finish()` in MainActivity?

Then, Check the FLAG on the intent which started the MainActivity. You might have used `FLAG_NO_HISTORY`. Which means the activity will be finish when it goes to background.